# Word 2013 - macro wouldn't apply cell padding values

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

Just a little bit of trouble here, I was trying to create just a simple macro to remove cell padding from all tables from a document, but for some unknown reason macro doesn't apply the settings. Manually (including when recording the macro) it works like a charm.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1, Name:=""
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1, Name:=""
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Tables(1).Select
With Selection.Cells(1)
    .TopPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.05)
    .BottomPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.05)
    .LeftPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.05)
    .RightPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0.05)
    .WordWrap = True
    .FitText = False
End With
End Sub
```

Any ideas? I've run out of any.

Cheers,
James

Comment: I’m confused.  You say you want to remove cell padding, but your code isn’t setting padding to 0.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Edit the question, title & body text are contradicting each other !

Comment: Modified the content. The cell padding value doesn't make any difference if is set to 0 or 0.05, thd macro will not apply any value, the cells have different values (the original ones,  unchanged)  in the same table

Comment: I am having a problem with this where some charts have padding and some don't when pasted from excel. I noticed there's 2 ways to set padding, for the whole table and cell by cell. The cell by cell one is in layout=>properties=>cell=>options, while the whole table one is in layout=>properties=>table=>options

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setup to alter only the first table in the document and then, only the first selected cell. The description of what you actually want is not clear, but I will assume you want to clear the margins on all table cells in all existing tables in the document.

```
Sub YouSayPaddingISayMargin()
'sets the default margin sizes for all
'existing tables in the document
Dim tbl As Word.Table
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.TopPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    tbl.BottomPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    tbl.LeftPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    tbl.RightPadding = CentimetersToPoints(0)
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Million thanks Rich, it worked like a charm, except for one table, which still keeps the old values, I have no idea why... The table has some merged columns on some rows, I don't know if this is affecting the macro or not. The margins are different as value only on those specific cells (with merged columns).

With the original macro, I tried to remove margins on the second table only, as that is the problematic one.

Comment: Are you able to adjust the margins manually in that one table? The merged cells are most likely what is blocking the macro from adjusting them globally.

Comment: Yup, as I mentioned earlier the manual adjustment it's working, but not the macro.